# PHP Notice: Undefined index: state

Tags: magento-1.9, rest-api

I am trying to use rest api on magento 1.9 from [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html).

My code is as follows.

```
    <?php
/**
* Example of simple product POST using Admin account via Magento REST API. OAuth authorization is used
*/
$callbackUrl = "http://yourhost/oauth_admin.php";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "http://magentohost/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'http://magentohost/admin/oauth_authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://magentohost/oauth/token';
$apiUrl = 'http://magentohost/api/rest';
$consumerKey = 'yourconsumerkey';
$consumerSecret = 'yourconsumersecret';

session_start();
if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
}
try {
    $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
    $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
    $oauthClient->enableDebug();

    if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
        $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
        header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
        exit;
    } else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
        $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
        exit;
    } else {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/products";
        $productData = json_encode(array(
            'type_id'           => 'simple',
            'attribute_set_id'  => 4,
            'sku'               => 'simple' . uniqid(),
            'weight'            => 1,
            'status'            => 1,
            'visibility'        => 4,
            'name'              => 'Simple Product',
            'description'       => 'Simple Description',
            'short_description' => 'Simple Short Description',
            'price'             => 99.95,
            'tax_class_id'      => 0,
        ));
        $headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/json');
        $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, $productData, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST, $headers);
        print_r($oauthClient->getLastResponseInfo());
    }
} catch (OAuthException $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
```

I've replaced yourhost with my host and filled the values for `$consumerKey`
and `$consumerSecret`.

I've saved this file as `myfile.php`.

When I run this script from terminal using command `php myfile.php` I get

`PHP Notice:  Undefined index: state in myfile.php on line 25
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: state in myfile.php on line 29`

Script is exiting from within the loop `if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state'])`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `if(!isset($_SESSION['state')) {
    $_SESSION['state'] = null;
}`
put this after `session_start();` line

Comment: after adding, there is no error, but no result too.
the script is still exiting from within `if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state'])`

Comment: you need to identify your condition.

Comment: Please elaborate.. I couldn't understand.

Comment: @MineshPatel regard API,  mycode :https://justpaste.it/6wu19  error : https://snag.gy/58mTUC.jpg can you pls help me?

Comment: @zus Oauth module is not installed. install Oauth module first.